# Burn fat while maintaining flexibility

Tags: weight-loss, strength, cardio, bodyweight-exercises, flexibility

I am a female aerialist (lyra, silks, etc.) And I have reached a point where I can not advance unless I burn some fat off my mid section. I'm not overweight but that is what I need to achieve however I cannot sacrifice my flexibility so from what I understand, most cardio is not an option. I have tried kettle bell exercises and where they helped me build my strength I gained mass in my gluten which made me more bottome heavy for aerial inversions. I'm not sure if there is a certain exercise that would allow me to target specific muscles or really what the best approach is.. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're looking for body recomp more than anything here. I would recommend just cutting the calories a little bit while maintaining relatively high protein.
The calorie in calorie out balance is really what you're gonna wanna play with here. If cutting the calories in doesn't sound like something you're up for, then I would recommend some light cardio like jogging or sitting on a rower or even swimming to increase the calories out. I think if you maintain a good stretching routine and cool down after your cardio sessions, this shouldn't have too much impact on your flexibility.